# Does the Google Analytics campaign measurement tracking for web-to-device was solved in v3 or v4?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

In Google Analytics SDK v2 for Android there is a section of [known issues](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#known-issues) stating that:
"Google Play Campaign Measurement does not currently support web-to-device installs initiated from the web Play Store"

On the [documentation of v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) the known issues section is missing and same goes for [v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns).

Does anyone knows if the problem with the web-to-device measurements was solved in v3 or v4?

From what I read in different places the problem is that the "INSTALL_REFERRER" is not broadcast by the system when the application was installed from the desktop-web play store.

Thanks,
Oded

Comment: So far from what I tested using SDK V4,  the problem still exists.